# Angular multitenant unable to "generate" shared components

Tags: angular, multi-tenant

For setting up a multitenant angular project, I followed the steps mentioned in this link:- 
[https://www.9lessons.info/2019/07/angular-multi-tenant-project.html](https://stackoverflow.com)

As was mentioned in the steps, initially, I was able to create a logo component under src/shared/shared-components/ (using the cli). So far so good.

But now, when I try to create another component under src/shared/shared-components/ cli is croaking like crazy with below error.
`
C:\xjs\projects\ng\multitenant1\src>npx ng g c ../shared/shared-components/somecomp
Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {"name":"../shared/shared-components/somecomp","path":"src"}
Errors:

Data path "" must have required property 'project'.`

Extra info:-

> > I am using v16.02 .
> > no build errors, and my tenants compiling fine using: "npx ng build multitenant1"

Problem in short:- In my multitenant angular 16 project, below command is failing with above error.
C:\xjs\projects\ng\multitenant1\src>npx ng g c ../shared/shared-components/somecomp

Kindly advise, i have spent several hours of productive time on this error.

Things I tried:-

1. installed schematic package but it still didn't work
2. installed cli globally and locally, but still same error. (without the npx command).
3. Tried "npm audit fix" , did not work.